# newly created fields values are not loaded with node_load

Tags: entities, nodes

I am loading nodes with node_load in one of my tpl.php, so i can get custom built teasers of nodes of specific content type in that tpl. Everything works fine, but from some unknown point of time i am not able to pull field values with node_load. Fields are included in node object, but there are no values in array!

For other custom fields i am able to get values, but for every newly created field- no value! (value is present in edit form and in database)

I am node_load-ing from tpl file of another content type. When i am trying to load those new fields from the tpl.php of its own content type, they are appearing.

But i see no logic because i have other custom fields that are being read with no problem.

Help please, i am pulling my hairs!

Answer (score 0):

Oops.

All my values are there. I was fooled by output, reading values from wrong nodes. I have complex loops here pulling out nodes so i was fooled.

How trivial :(